# AJAX is not working in child repeater data bind

Tags: repeater

i have a Parent repeater and one child repeater which is inside parent repeater.

From a text box i am posting some contents to parent repeater which works with AJAX update panel (without posting back page), but from another text box if i am posting to child repeater, then i checked table the data was inserted but its not displaying in child repeater. Once i will refresh my page then data in child repeater will display.

How can i achieve this without page postback. i.e. i want to do it with client side either AJAX or, java script or jquery. kindly provide the code.